# Limit GPU Resource to a particular process

Tags: linux, gpu, cgroups, ulimit

The `ulimit` command can limit the memory to a process in the Linux machine. Similarly, is there any command in Linux to run a process with limited GPU resource. For example, I have a 64 GB GPU machine, I want to limit a certain process(YOLO) to use only 1 GB of GPU for some experimental reason.